# Filter WordPress search results between different (custom) post types

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I have an search.php file, which shows the search results of the user's search, using this code:

```
<?php
$s=get_search_query();
$args = array('s' =>$s);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?>

  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
     ?>
      <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
  <?php } 

}else{ ?>
  <h1>No search results found</h1>
<?php } 

?>
```

Is there a way, where I can filter the results between different (custom) post types?

Like this:

```
- item1 (post)
- item2 (custom post type named 'clients')
- item3 (custom post type named 'clients')
- item4 (custom post type named 'occasions')
- item5 (post)
```

Comment: `<h1><?php the_title(); ?> (<?php echo get_post_type(); ?>)</h1>

Comment: That worked perfectly! Could you post this as answer? So I can approve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to display the post `post_type` in your loop :

```
<h1><?php the_title(); ?> (<?php echo get_post_type(); ?>)</h1>
```

And ideally, you should add `wp_reset_postdata();` after the closing of `while` loop, to keep clean the bottom of your page :

```
<?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ){
    $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?> (<?php echo get_post_type(); ?>)</h1>
<?php } 
wp_reset_postdata();
```